# Navigation between subview and superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my program,I called subview from main superview with the following code:                                                                                        [self.viewaddSubview:mysubView.view];                                                         I want to navigate from subview to previous superview like 'back function'.How can do like that?                                                                                         For My project,I use xCode 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use methods removeFromSuperview and bringSubviewToFront.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is basic navigation bar functionality with a "back" button.

Check out UINavigationController and these two functions

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

at this documentation page:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

yes.You can,
sendSubviewToBack:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:mysubView.view];
```

or

```
[mysubView.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the object of subview in superView  and store them into an array and than remove them according to there index position. If you use only single subview in super view than follow this code :

```
NSArray *arr = [SuperView subviews];

NSLog ("objects in arr %@",arr);

[[arr objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```